# How to access enclosed element's Variable annotations in annotation processor?

Tags: java, kotlin, annotation-processing, annotation-processor, kotlinpoet

I am creating a string of data class for our API optimization like this

data class ex:

```
@MyAnnotation
data class Cast( 
     @Json(name = "cast_id") 
     val castId: Int, 

     val name: String, 

     @Json(name = "profile_path") 
     val profilePath: String? 
)
```

wanted result:

> {"cast_id":1, "name":1, "profile_path":1}

but currently able to generate it

> "{"castId":1, "name":1, "profilePath":1}"

I want access **@JSON (or @SerializedName)** annotation and its value, how do I get it?

then Using Kotlin poet to create class with this string init.

Comment: Could you please add more details? What JSON serializer are you using? If you need to change naming strategy using serialization library e.g. Jackson, source code generation is an overkill.

Comment: This not for serialization, This string will be used as a query param in API. I also want make it flexible to support both Moshi and GSON.